# Can I close a file descriptor inside a signal handler?

Tags: c, signals

currently in my classes we were learning how we can handle signals in C. I found it very interesting so I was messing around with it to try and learn it nicely.
Here's the problem: I wanted to make a program that reads from stdin on an infinite loop and writes whatever is inputed in to a file. When I want it to stop I would just use `CTRL + C` and terminate the program.
I wanted to mess around with the signal function to make this terminate more gracefully, however it doesn't work. Can anyone tell me how to get the desired behavior?
This is my code:

```c
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

void sigint_handler (int signum) {
    printf("\nTerminating program...\n");
    close(fd);
    _exit(0);
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    signal(SIGINT, sigint_handler);
    int fd;
    if ((fd = open("client", O_WRONLY | O_CREAT)) == -1) {
        perror("Error opening file");
        return 1;
    }
    int len = 0;
    char buffer[1024];
    while ((len = read(STDIN_FILENO, buffer, 1024)) > 0) {
        write(fd, buffer, len);
    }
    printf("Terminated\n");
    close(fd);
    return 0;
}
```

The point was to inside the `sigint_handler()` function, it would close the file descriptor and the terminate the program.
However, I can't do this. Is there a better way to get the desired result?
Or is it okay to terminate the program without closing the file descriptor?
If anyone can help me understand this better I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Another way would be to poll the input file descriptor and only read from it once input is ready. That would avoid the blocking call to read(), so then in the signal handler you could just set a flag. In the poll loop you would then check for the flag and exit gracefully if needed.

Comment: Using stdio functions in a signal handler isn't safe

Comment: But `close()` is allowed by posix. The variable holding the descriptor to close has to be in scope of the handler function, of course. And they get closed anyway when the program exits...

Comment: A good resource for what you can use in a signal handler is https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal-safety.7.html (if restricted to strictly standard C instead of posix the options are *much* more limited)

Comment: @Shawn Thank you, I will look into it. Also can you explain further on why you should avoid using stdio functions in a signal handler?

Comment: The documentation I linked elaborates more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

#define TERMINATING "\nTerminating program...\n"

void sigint_handler (int signum) {
    // you can use write to avoid issues raised by @Shawn
    write(2, TERMIATING, sizeof(TERMINATING));
    _exit(0); /* close is not needed _exit guarantees the close */
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
    int fd;
    if ((fd = open("client", O_WRONLY | O_CREAT)) == -1) {
        perror("Error opening file");
        return 1;
    }

    // install signal handler ONLY AFTER successfully opening fd
    signal(SIGINT, sigint_handler);

    int len = 0;
    char buffer[1024];
    while ((len = read(STDIN_FILENO, buffer, 1024)) > 0) {
        write(fd, buffer, len);
    }
    // print messages like this to stderr 
    fprintf(stderr, "Terminated\n");
    close(fd); // superfluous because you are about exit
    return 0;
}
```

<strike>Better way to do the handler would be to keep fd local to main however to use `exit(0)` instead of `_exit` because `exit(0)` will cause the kernel to close any files that are open.</strike>

What I meant to say was (thank you @John Gordon) is that it's better to use exit(0) to ensure that any exit handlers are also called as needed.

Comment: According to the _exit(2) man page on linux, "Any open file descriptors belonging to the process are closed." What _exit(2) doesn't do that exit(3) does is to call any exit handlers registered with atexit(3).

Comment: my brain wanted to type something else, and ended up typing this.

Comment: *to ensure that any exit handlers are also called as needed.*  Which you **can't** safely do from within a signal handler since exit handlers will not be async-signal-safe.  Exit handlers will include flushing `stdout`, which is not async-signal-safe.